# How to solve CORS Origin issue when trying to get data of a json file from localhost

Tags: javascript, jquery, cors

I was trying to get the data from a json file (which is on the remote server) from localhost and I am getting error '**from origin 'http://localhost:5000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**'

Below is the code I used to send the get request.

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://abc/some.json',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Request-Headers": "*",
            "Access-Control-Request-Method": "*",
            'Content-Type':'application/json'
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
            chatbotConfig = data;
            console.log(chatbotConfig);
        }
    })
```

I am able to get the data using postman. I understand that postman is not a browser so it is not limited by CORS policy. But I am able to download the content from json file directly from the browser. Nit able to understand why I am facing issue when I tried to access from localhost. Can any one please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: You need the local server to return those headers. + Getting CORS error is only when using AJAX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the CORS error may lie in different layers of your application. Usually, by allowing all (`*`) origins and headers in the server-side, your problem should be fixed. But sometimes it won't and it lies somewhere else like your HTTP request header or body, DNS settings *(Making sure there are no third-party DNS set in your network by yourself through the OS)*, or browser settings. So I will describe all of the possible solutions here shortly.

**NOTE:** You can read more about CORS policy [here](https://javascript.info/fetch-crossorigin#why-is-cors-needed-a-brief-history).

### How to solve CORS error

If you have access to your server-side settings and/or options you need to make sure *(Or if you don't you need to ask your backend developer)* that everything set correctly there or not. So the steps will be as follows:

- First of all, you need to make sure your server configs for CORS are set correctly.

  1. So for example, if you are using [Apache](https://apache.org/) you can set the CORS policy in your `.htaccess` file like this (or simply check if it exists):

  ```
  // This will allow all origins to access your server
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" // You can set * to whatever domain
  Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "*"
  ```

  2. If you are using [nodeJS](https://nodejs.org/api/) you can check or set it like this:

  ```js
   app.use((req, res, next) => {
      res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      res.header(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
      );
      next();
   });
  ```

  3. If you are using [Nginx](https://www.nginx.com/) you can check or set it in `nginx.conf` like this:

  ```
  server {
    location / {
       add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
       add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "*";
    }
  }
  ```

  4. If you use any other service for your server-side you should read the documentation about it, but all of them are actually same.
- If you checked the above step and CORS policy was set correctly in your server-side, you may need to check your HTTP request and make sure everything is set correctly there. For example, there is no need to add these two headers

  ```
  "Access-Control-Request-Headers": "*",
  "Access-Control-Request-Method": "*",
  ```

  in your request, because they do not exist as a header in the client-side. Wrong HTTP request API end-point address or options (like `dataType`), wrong HTTP request body or headers may also cause the CORS error for your here. So you need to check them all and make sure you are set them correctly.
- If none of the above was the problem you can try two other approaches. I mostly encourage to use the second one if none of the above solves your problem.

  1. Mapping your `localhost` to a URL using your `hosts` file (Usually lies under `etc` folder in each operating system). You can do that like this (But it's better to read the documentation for each OS).

     ```
     127.0.0.1   www.test.com ## map 127.0.0.1 to www.test.com
     ## or
     localhost   www.test.com
     ```

     **NOTE:** Usually it is better to avoid this approach.
  2. Use browser plugins like [Allow CORS](https://mybrowseraddon.com/access-control-allow-origin.html).

Comment: With Chrome, I know you can also set the option: `--allow-file-access-from-files` to stop local file access (via file://) throwing a CORS origin error.But I'm not sure if that stops it being an issue with localhost.

And I'm not sure what the other security implications are of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Basically if you clearly look into the issue logs:
'from origin 'http://localhost:5000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

It's saying CORS not enabled at resource. which means it need to be fixed or allowed at server side.